# Getting NullPointerException using Service after closing app

Tags: java, android, httprequest, intentservice

I have used to create AlarmService with IntentService which executes another class TakeUserData. That class makes some HTTP requests. When app is open, all works fine but after closing process I'm getting java.lang.NullPointerException on each service call.

**Here's logcat:**

```
01-23 16:27:00.999  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getLang(VKRequest.java:548)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getPreparedParameters(VKRequest.java:274)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.httpClient.VKHttpClient.requestWithVkRequest(VKHttpClient.java:127)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getPreparedRequest(VKRequest.java:297)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getOperation(VKRequest.java:311)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.vk.sdk.api.VKBatchRequest.executeWithListener(VKBatchRequest.java:76)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.eugnis.vktrace.TakeUserData.<init>(TakeUserData.java:91)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at com.eugnis.vktrace.CheckUsersService.onHandleIntent(CheckUsersService.java:107)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
    01-23 16:27:01.009  18276-18290/com.eugnis.vktrace W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

**And IntentService class:**

```
package com.eugnis.vktrace;
...

public class CheckUsersService extends IntentService {
    SaveUserData dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    TakeUserData take;

    public CheckUsersService() {
        super("CheckUsersService");
    }



    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        Log.d("ABAB", "ON START COMMAND");
        try {
            dbHelper = new SaveUserData(this);
            db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor c = db.query("users", null, null, null, null, null, null);
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                int useridColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("userid");
                do {
                    int userID = c.getInt(useridColIndex);
                    take = new TakeUserData(this, userID, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1);
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            } else
                Log.d("VkDemoApp", "0 rows");
            c.close();
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Timed alarm onReceive() started at time: " + new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.d("ABAB", "INTENT STARTED");
    }
}
```

**TakeUserData:**

```
public class TakeUserData {

    SaveUserData dbHelper;
    String selection = null;
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    int online=0, friends=0, status=0, pagedata=0, photovideo=0, music=0, groups=0, posts=0;
    VKApiUserFull userInfo;
    Context context;
    private static final int NOTIFY_ID = 101;

    public TakeUserData(Context v, final int userID, final int chkonline, final int chkfriends, final int chkpagedata, final int chkphotovideo, final int chkmusic, final int chkgroups, final int chkposts)
    {
        context=v;
        dbHelper = new SaveUserData(context);

        final SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        Log.d("VkDemoApp", "--- Rows in mytable: ---");

        selection = "userid="+userID;
        Cursor c = db.query("users", null, selection, null, null, null, null);

        if(c.getCount()==1) {
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                int onlineColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("online");
                int friendsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("friends");
                //  int statusColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("status");
                int pagedataColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("pagedata");
                int photovideoColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("photovideo");
                int musicColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("music");
                int groupsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("groups");
                int postsColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("posts");

                online = c.getInt(onlineColIndex);
                friends = c.getInt(friendsColIndex);
                pagedata = c.getInt(pagedataColIndex);
                photovideo = c.getInt(photovideoColIndex);
                music = c.getInt(musicColIndex);
                groups = c.getInt(groupsColIndex);
                posts = c.getInt(postsColIndex);

            } else
                Log.d("VkDemoApp", "0 rows");
            c.close();
        }



        if (c.moveToFirst()) {

            VKRequest requestUserInformation = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.USER_ID, userID, VKApiConst.FIELDS, "photo_200, counters, last_seen, status, photo_id, city, contacts, education, relatives, relation, personal, connections, activities, interests, music, movies, tv, books, games, about, quotes"));
            VKRequest requestUserPosts = VKApi.wall().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.OWNER_ID, userID));
            VKBatchRequest batch = new VKBatchRequest(requestUserInformation, requestUserPosts);


            batch.executeWithListener(new VKBatchRequest.VKBatchRequestListener() {  //Error from this column
                @Override

                public void onComplete(VKResponse[] responses) {

                    String tlast_seen=null, tfriends_count=null, tsubscribers_count=null, tphoto_200=null, tcity=null, tmobile_phone=null, thome_phone=null,
                            trelatives=null, trelation=null, tpersonal=null, tconnections=null, tactivities=null, tinterests=null, tmovies=null, ttv=null, tbooks=null,
                            tgames=null, tabout=null, tquotes=null, tphoto_count=null, tvideo_count=null, tmusic_count=null, tgroups_count=null, tposts_count=null;

                    super.onComplete(responses);
                    Log.d("VkDemoApp", "TakeResp1 " + responses[0].json.toString());
                    Log.d("VkDemoApp", "TakeResp2 " + responses[1].json);
                    userInfo = ((VKList<VKApiUserFull>)responses[0].parsedModel).get(0);
                    String[] arrayPosts = responses[1].json.toString().split("(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

                    ...

    }
           @Override
            public void onError(VKError error) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Error" + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    } else
        Log.d("VkDemoApp", "0 rows");
    c.close();

}
```

Checked to launch without HTTP requests - all is good. I'm sure it's because HTTP requests but I don't know how to fix it.

**VKRequest.getLang**

```
private String getLang() {
    String result = mPreferredLang;
    if (useSystemLanguage) {
        result = VKUIHelper.getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
        if (result.equals("uk")) {
            result = "ua";
        }

        if (!Arrays.asList(new String[]{"ru", "en", "ua", "es", "fi", "de", "it"})
                .contains(result)) {
            result = mPreferredLang;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

**VKUIHelper.java**

```
public class VKUIHelper {
    private static Activity sTopActivity;
    private static Context  sApplicationContext;

    public static Activity getTopActivity()
    {
        return sTopActivity;
    }
    public static Context getApplicationContext() { return sApplicationContext; }
    /**
     * Call it in onCreate for of activities where you using VK SDK
     * @param activity Your activity
     */
    public static void onCreate(Activity activity)
    {
        if (sTopActivity != activity)
            sTopActivity = activity;
        if (sApplicationContext == null && activity != null) {
            sApplicationContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call it in onResume for of activities where you using VK SDK
     * @param activity Your activity
     */
    public static void onResume(Activity activity)
    {
        if (sTopActivity != activity)
            sTopActivity = activity;
        if (sApplicationContext == null && activity != null) {
            sApplicationContext = activity.getApplicationContext();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call it in onDestroy for of activities where you using VK SDK
     * @param activity Your activity
     */
    public static void onDestroy(Activity activity)
    {
        if (sTopActivity == activity)
            sTopActivity = null;
    }

    /**
     * Call it in onActivityResult of all activities where you using VK SDK
     * @param requestCode Request code for startActivityForResult
     * @param resultCode Result code of finished activity
     * @param data Result data
     * @deprecated Use onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) instead
     */
    public static void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        onActivityResult(sTopActivity, requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    /**
     * Call it in onActivityResult of all activities where you using VK SDK
     * @param requestCode Request code for startActivityForResult
     * @param resultCode Result code of finished activity
     * @param data Result data
     */
    public static void onActivityResult(Activity activity, int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        sTopActivity = activity;
        if (requestCode == VKSdk.VK_SDK_REQUEST_CODE) {
            VKSdk.processActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: problem is in `TakeUserData` so post TakeUserData class code

Comment: does `c.getInt(useridColIndex)` give you a valid integer?

Comment: @Steffen yes, it's valid. I think it's problem in wrong context while executing another class new TakeUserData(this, userID, 1,1,1,1,1,1,1); this belongs to Context

Comment: You shouldn't override `onStartCommand` in your `IntentService`. Work should be done in `onHandleIntent`. Here's the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: @darnmason Have tried putting all work code in `onHandleIntent` without `onStartCommand`. Getting same error after closing app

Comment: Well that wasn't a solution to your problem, which is why I commented, you'll have to post the code where the exception is occurring: `com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.getAccessToken(VKSdk.java:344)`

Comment: @Eugnis: what is line number `92` in `TakeUserData`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK `batch.executeWithListener(new VKBatchRequest.VKBatchRequestListener() {` it used to make HTTP requests

Comment: @darnmason Have fixed error in VKSdk.java but problem not solved. Updated new Logcat

Comment: Well keep fixing the errors until you don't have any more... new one is a null at `com.vk.sdk.api.VKRequest.getLang(VKRequest.java:548)`

Comment: @darnmason Added `VKRequest.getLang` code. Here's column which causing exception `result = VKUIHelper.getApplicationContext().getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();` I guess problem in `getApplicationContext()` but don`t know how to fix

Comment: Well post `VKUIHelper` to see why that would be returning null

Comment: @darnmason `VKUIHelper` posted

Comment: So are you sure sApplicationContext is set? Just debug the application and step through it to find what's null

Comment: @darnmason Ok, after closing process service restarts with null context so it may cause that exception. Have tried to use `getApplicationContext()` and `IntentService.this`. Both not working

Comment: I don't know if you solved this issue or not but try this in your intent service: final Context context = this. I'm not sure if it will help. Anyway, if you solve this please post your answer.

Comment: @Karim No, still not solved. I've tried final Context, but getting same exception.